# SQL query to only retrieve records which match a list or its subset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on analyzing Add/Remove Program data from our SCCM server and need some assistance with a query.

The data has been retrieved from SCCM and scrubbed so that I'm only left with a list of actual applications I'm interested in. Common apps/security updates/runtimes, etc have been filtered out.

I need to define an SQL query which will give me a list of computers and their applications only if they have one or more applications defined by a list.

e.g.

```
Computer    | Application
--------------------------------------
WKS001      | Microsoft Office
WKS001      | WebEx
WKS001      | Java Runtime 1.6_33
--------------------------------------
WKS002      | Microsoft Office
WKS002      | WebEx
WKS002      | Java Runtime 1.6_33
WKS002      | Photoshop
--------------------------------------
WKS003      | WebEx
WKS003      | Java Runtime 1.6_33
--------------------------------------
WKS004      | WebEx
WKS004      | Photoshop
```

I need to retrieve all computers which have any or all of the following applications:

```
Microsoft Office
WebEx
Java Runtime 1.6_33
```

That should give me  `WKS001` and `WKS003`

Comment: So you excluded `WKS002` and `WSK004` since those computers have more than the 3 targeted applications?

Comment: yep, that's how I should have worded it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to *exclude* computers that have an application not in that list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Computer
FROM Table AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table AS t2 ON t1.Computer = t2.Computer
    AND t2.Application NOT IN ('Microsoft Office','WebEx','Java Runtime 1.6_33')
WHERE t1.Application IN ('Microsoft Office','WebEx','Java Runtime 1.6_33')
  AND t2.Computer IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Computer, Application
FROM TABLE_NAME_HERE
WHERE Application='Microsoft Office' 
   OR Application='WebEx' 
   OR Application='Java Runtime 1.6_33'
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't bring back the computer's applications. Try this:

```
SELECT
    computer
    ,application
FROM
    TABLENAME 
WHERE
    computer IN
        (
            SELECT
                computer
            FROM
                TABLENAME
            WHERE
                application IN
                    (
                        'Microsoft Office'
                        ,'WebEx'
                        ,'Java Runtime 1.6_33'
                    )
        )
    AND comptuer NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT
                computer
            FROM
                TABLENAME
            WHERE
                application NOT IN
                    (
                        'Microsoft Office'
                        ,'WebEx'
                        ,'Java Runtime 1.6_33'
                    )
        )
```